# Way to create a notification in Android considering Android O

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-intentservice

What I am trying to understand is the way to create a notification that will check the current date of the system(Tablet or Phone) and match the dates that I am getting from the server. The data is JSON data.
This will be checked every day and if the dates match then the system will give notification to the user otherwise no notification, this should be checked at a particular time.
Now how to do so? 
Create a service or a broadcast receiver or any other way?
Please Help.
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to happen this at a specified time on each day better to use AlarmManager. If time is not a constraint you can use WorkManager

Comment: Thank you @p.mathew13 for replying so fast. So basically using alarmManager I run a code I want to run every day at a particular time? I also want to display a notification. How to do that? Shall I use broadcastReciever or is there another way.

Comment: Yes, If you want to display a notification better to use a combination of Alarm manager + Broadcast Receiver